# How to filter array only it not in another arrays value

Tags: jquery, filter

I have 2 arrays, in this 2 i need a out put of the array, which only exist on 2'nd array. i tried this but no reust;

```
var x = ["apple","2","3", "4", "3", "x", "M"], y = ["4","5","apple","zoo"];

var z = y.filter(function(){
    return $.inArray(y,x) === -1;
})

console.log(z); i am looking for ["5","zoo"]
```

how do i filter like this.. any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var x = ["apple","2","3", "4", "3", "x", "M"], y = ["4","5","apple","zoo"];

var z = $.map(y, function(val, idx){
    return $.inArray(val, x) === -1 ? val : undefined;
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3v3Dw/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = ["apple","2","3", "4", "3", "x", "M"]
,   y = ["4","5","apple","zoo"]
,   result = [];
$.each(x, function (i, v) {
    if ($.inArray(v, y) !== -1) {
        result.push(v);
    }
});
console.log(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/svCys/1